# The volume of the figure formed by rotation around x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume of the figure obtained by rotation around x-axis, bounded by: $xy = a^2$, $y = 0$, $x = a$, $x = 2a$.
I have trouble to set the integration bounds. I know that the volume can be calculated by using
$$V = \pi \int_{a}^{b} f^2(x) dx$$
How to proceed?

Comment: Actually: $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$ and $f(x)^2=(f(x))^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a>0$ just  calculate 
$$\pi\int\limits_a^{2a}\left(\frac{a^2}{x}\right)^2dx.$$

The case $a<0$ for you.

Answer (score 1):

The volume desired is
$$V=\pi\int_a^{2a}\left(\frac{a^2}{x}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x$$